# Should I change dependency version of admob unity to match firebase?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

I was using admob, gcm & google analytics. 
Now I'm moving to firebase. But neither analytics nor admob works with firebase. For analytics moving to firebase analytics. But admob is needed.

Problem is because, firebase uses play services version 11.0.0 specifically. 
But admob & google analytics uses version "LATEST".

Now jar resolvers pulling 11.0.0 for firebase and for other two taking 11.0.2.  And therefore duplicate classes are there and build fails.

I can solve it by changing the "LATEST" to 11.0.0 in admob's dependency resolver class.

But is it safe & recommended to do? As I'm changing the 3rd party plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use Admob with Firebase since [Admob is officialy a part of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase) so there should be no worries in doing this.

> The best way to use AdMob is with Firebase, but for those publishers
>   who aren't ready to make the switch just yet, the Google Mobile Ads
>   SDK can be used as a [standalone
>   SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/).

Comment: For unity3d AdMob is not a part of firebase sdk. Its a standalone one & the google mobile ad is the one only.  Thats why the problem. Can I change dependency version to match both firebase and google mobile ads sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a test another alternative plugin.

https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity

This on include all dependence lib,it more easy to change dependence .
The way to change the dependence is replace libs under the libs folder.